# ksqlDB not taking rowkey properly

Tags: ksqldb, confluent-platform

I have produced following data on topic named SENSOR_STATUS_DETAILS in **json**:

```
1001
{
  "sensorid": 1001,
  "status": "CONNECTED",
  "lastconnectedtime": "2020-05-31 22:31:54"
}
1002
{
  "sensorid": 1002,
  "status": "CONNECTED",
  "lastconnectedtime": "2020-05-31 22:33:37"
}
```

I am trying to make a table from it as:

```
CREATE TABLE STATUS_IB_TABLE (ROWKEY INT KEY,
  sensorid INTEGER,
  status VARCHAR,
  lastconnectedtime STRING)
WITH (TIMESTAMP='lastconnectedtime', TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', KAFKA_TOPIC='SENSOR_STATUS_DETAILS', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', KEY='sensorid');
```

The rowkey ksqlDB is making is as follows:

[image]

I want the rowkey to be **sensorid**....
I don't know whats happening

please help me on this.

thanks in advance!!

PS:

Confluent Platform version: **5.5**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the data being produced to the Kafka topic `SENSOR_STATUS_DETAILS` has a `STRING` key, not an `INT` key.

If you take the `STRING` `"1001"` it just happens to serialize to the same number of bytes as an `INT`.  If you deserialize those same bytes as an `INT` you get the number `825241649`.

You have two options:

1. Change how you are producing the data so that you are producing a serialized 32-bit integer as the Kafka message's key and continue to import as `ROWKEY INT KEY`, or
2. Change your `CREATE TABLE` statement to have a `STRING` key:

   `CREATE TABLE STATUS_IB_TABLE (
        ROWKEY STRING KEY,  // <-- string key
        sensorid STRING,    // <-- matching type here.
        status VARCHAR,
        lastconnectedtime STRING
   )
   WITH (<as above>);`

The first option would likely result in slightly better performance

Comment: First off thank you very much @AndrewCoates, the 2nd Option worked...
I am using REST Proxy program to produce data on topic....
I have posted the code in my follow up question: [**Kafka producing message key as STRING even though the REST program has INT?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62152765/kafka-producing-message-key-as-string-even-though-the-rest-program-has-int)
Please have a look at it and help me solve the problem...
thanks once again....